# Gitlab The term 'bundle' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: flutter, gitlab, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am trying to implement CI/CD for flutter with gitlab. I am using fastlane to deploy the app to firebase for distribution.

my script inside .gitlab-ci.yml is following

```
stages:
  - build # All jobs related for building app for iOS/Android
  - deploy

flutter_build_android: #Job name
  stage: build # kind of
  before_script:
    - cd android
    - bundle install --deployment
  script:
    - bundle exec fastlane build
  artifacts:
  paths:
    - build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk
  tags:
    - cd

deploy_android:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - cd android
    - bundle install --deployment
  dependencies:
    - flutter_build_android
  script:
    - bundle exec fastlane deploy_beta
  tags:
    - cd
```

[image: And this is error gitlab shows]

Answer (score 0):

The `bundle` command is from the `bundler` Ruby package. To use it you need to ensure `bundler` is installed.

Try adding `gem install bundler` in your `before_script`

If you cannot use ruby for some reason you can omit the `bundle exec` and fastlane will whine at you but it will still work.

Also if you didnt know, you can make a `before_script` base level step in the yaml like so and you dont have to keep copying and pasting it

```yaml
stages:
  - build # All jobs related for building app for iOS/Android
  - deploy

before_script:
  - gem install bundler
  - cd android
  - bundle install --deployment

flutter_build_android: #Job name
  stage: build # kind of
  script:
    - bundle exec fastlane build
  artifacts:
  paths:
    - build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk
  tags:
    - cd

deploy_android:
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - flutter_build_android
  script:
    - bundle exec fastlane deploy_beta
  tags:
    - cd
```